# C# How to implement a function in this code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] values = { "10x", "10", "100xx" };
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                int flag;
                if (int.TryParse(value, out flag))
                    Console.WriteLine(" '{0}' is a number.", value, flag);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(" '{0}' is not a number.", value == null ? "<null>" : value);
            }

        }
```

This is the code so far. And i have to implement a function which can receive a string parameter and return a bool type variable. Then the function must verify if the said sent parameter is integer and return true if it is or false if it isn't. Can you please help? i am new to C# and trying to learn on my own. Thank you.

Comment: Which function? .. you havent made one yet

Comment: You're asking about having parameters passed in, but you already have an array passed without even using it

Comment: The question i asked is the second point of the exercise the first one said to build a function who receives a string parameter and returns a bool variable. The function then must verify if the sent parameter is a int and return true if it is or false if it isn't. In Main the function must be called once with a param which is a number and once with a param who isn't a number

Comment: from what you said it means i did it wrong

Comment: Does numbers mean integer and decimals - ie 10.2?  Are comma separators allowed (NOTE: other countries culture use decimal as their thousands separator).

Comment: no.. just integers

Answer (score 2):

This function, a very special main function already can accept many arguments.

Your code does not use any of the passed in values.

BTW. The first WriteLine doesn't write out the 'flag'.